# Flutter paint: How to build progress bar with complex cutom shape? (see picture)

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to implement this progress bar. I tried several different ideas using CustomPaint, but couldn't implement it properly. The advice related to "architecture" of this is pretty enough, I'm good with coding.

Any help, any ideas appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: So what was the problem in using Custompaint? the green shadow, the arc near the bulge or the image?

Comment: @bluevoid but how can I do the progress bar from that? I mean I need to fill the whole shape smoothly from left to right
Moreover, the rocket also should be smoothly changed from blue to white

Comment: What I have been doing is let the custompainter listen to a value(lets call it X) in a provider model which changes the progress. The smoothness depends on the step size in which X increases. If the steps are to big you can add a timer which increases to the new value of X in small steps. So if X = 10 and the new value is 50, then let the timer update the value with 1 every 20ms or so and then call notify on your provider model. The custom painter repaints itself with a small increase till 50 is reached. By this you set a max speed in which the progressbar increases, giving it a smooth look.

Comment: @bluevoid It's clear how to implement the animations. I've just used AnimatedBuilder and repaint it depending on animation value. The question is how to draw it properly? How to create such a shape? How to change the color of the blue rocket which becomes white? I've implemented it, animations work good but the whole progress bar still looks pretty ugly.

Comment: draw the rocket in white, set clip to the part of the rocket you want to be blue, overdraw with blue rocket. For the rest of the green shape: create a polyline, or build it from pieces (line, circle, 2 triangles ) or have a look at custom drawing of svg

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Will try. 
Now I really think to use a lottie animation instead of painting it by code. Looks really difficult for me.

Comment: Lottie is promising, did not know it is working on flutter already